# Why is header's css not loading correctly on a specific page in IE?

Tags: css

The page not working in IE8 is http://gainntrain.com/shopping/index.php
It IS working chrome and firefox...
This page loads from CubeCart, but the page I edited to alter the skin http://gainntrain.com/shopping/skins/KitaBlue/styleTemplates/global/index.tpl

That page has the same problem in IE8

The thing I don't understand is that the same header works fine on other pages of the site in IE8

---

Changed the `<header>` and `<nav>` tags to divs with classes using the styles that the tags had and that seems to be handling it just fine so thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Look at 
[Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://gainntrain.com/shopping/index.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) 
and 
[Jigsaw](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://www.gainntrain.com/site/css/style.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) 
Notice that the only errors in Jigsaw are CSS3 rules.
I would suggest looking at the HTML because of this line in Validator's analysis of your page

```
    Line 11, Column 107: end tag for "link" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
…="http://www.gainntrain.com/site/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
✉
You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".
```

It looks like your document is using HTML5 features but is using an older doctype declaration. I would suggest changing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
```

That is as long as it doesn't break the site. :]

Comment: Ok I see that xhtml doesn't accept <header> and <nav> tags so obviously that's the problem. Now I don't understand exactly why it doesn't accept those tags and what possible replacements there are.

Comment: I personally use Paul Irish's HTML5 Boilerplate on new sites and HTML5 Shiv for older sites I want to add HTML5 tags to. Look at http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ and http://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try an online HTML validator on the output, like [this one](http://infohound.net/tidy/). If you choose the right validator, it's likely to be able to pick out the sticky bits that work better in some browsers than others. Sifting through code by hand to find a solution like this is difficult and time-consuming.